# Optimization flag to remove redundant record allocations in F# code?

Tags: f#

Consider this code:

```ml
type Foo = 
  {
    X : int
    Y : string
    Z : int
  }
  
module M = 

  let f foo = 
    let foo = 
      {
        foo with
          X = 123
      }
      
    let foo = 
      {
        foo with
          Y = "abc"
      }
      
    let foo = 
      {
        foo with
          X = foo.X + 1
      }
   
    foo
    
  let g foo =
    {
      foo with
        X = 123 + 1
        Y = "abc"
    }
```

Note that `f` and `g` do the same.

Using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io), this is equivalent to:

```cs
// ...

    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
    public static class M
    {
        public static Foo f(Foo foo)
        {
            Foo foo2 = new Foo(123, foo.Y@, foo.Z@);
            Foo foo3 = new Foo(123, "abc", foo2.Z@);
            return new Foo(124, "abc", foo3.Z@);
        }

        public static Foo g(Foo foo)
        {
            return new Foo(124, "abc", foo.Z@);
        }
    }

// ...
```

Despite achieving the same thing, `f` allocates 3 times and `g` only once.

Is there a compiler flag or similar I can use to get `f` to compile more like `g`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost certain what you're asking for doesn't exist and that every `with` involves a new copy. Adding the `[<Struct>]` attribute to your record might give you more performant allocation. See here for more details: https://bartoszsypytkowski.com/writing-high-performance-f-code/